# not declared in this scope in the case of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope

I have a file `my_node.h`. In this file I declare a Stack class:

```
template<class Datatype>
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack() : head( NULL )
        {

        }
        virtual ~Stack()
        {
            Datatype temp;
            while (pop(temp));
            cout << "Stack released all spaces" << endl;
        }
    public:
        virtual int push(Datatype &);
        virtual int pop(Datatype &);
        virtual Datatype* peek();
    protected:
        Node<Datatype> *head;
};
```

Then, I have another file called new_stack.h. In this file, I wrote a inheritance class of Stack, which is StackWithDeep. The code is shown below:

```
#include "my_node.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<class Datatype>
class StackWithDeep : public Stack<Datatype>
{
    public:
        StackWithDeep(int thre) : Stack<Datatype>()
        {
            stack_deep = 0;
            limited_deep = thre;
        }
        virtual ~StackWithDeep()
        {
        }
    public:
        virtual int push(Datatype &);
        virtual int pop(Datatype &);
        int getdeep()
        {
            return stack_deep;
        }
    private:
        int stack_deep;
        int limited_deep;
};

template<class Datatype>
int StackWithDeep<Datatype>::push(Datatype &new_data)
{
    Node<Datatype> *pt_node = new Node<Datatype>;
    if (pt_node == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (stack_deep != limited_deep)
    {
        pt_node -> addData(new_data);

        if (head == NULL)
            head = pt_node;
        else
        {
            pt_node -> addPrev(*head);
            head = pt_node;
        }
        stack_deep ++;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        delete pt_node;
        return 0;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to implement a push(). However, when I compile, the compiler said:

```
In member function ‘virtual int StackWithDeep<Datatype>::push(Datatype&)’:
error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
```

I think I can use this `head` pointer because it's protected in class Stack and my new class do inheritance publicly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Standard says that unqualified names in a template are generally
 non-dependent and must be looked up when the template is defined.
 Since the definition of a dependent base class is not known at that
 time (there may be specialisations of the base class template that
 have not yet been seen), unqualified names are never resolved to
 members of the dependent base class. Where names in the template are
 supposed to refer to base class members or to indirect base classes,
 they can either be made dependent by qualifying them or brought into
 the template's scope with a using-declaration
```

Use `this->head` that will work...

Answer (score 0):

Your code flow worked correctly in VS2012 . But in Ideone.com it failed.

Where ever you are using head in derived class, qualify it with the base class as follows: `Stack<Datatype>::head` . This worked for me.